# Pattern(s) sought for avoiding "action at a distance"

Tags: perl, design-patterns, cpan, moose, dancer

I'm working on a complex and very large web application. Some of the classes within said application require execution of various methods in far-away objects, and I am quickly realizing and stumbling into bugs related to the "action at a distance" antipattern.

Example 1: Some of the classes require execution of daily "cleanup" methods, such as `reaper()`, `cleanup()`, `send_daily_status_messages()`, etc.

Example 2: Some classes mutate the app's state, and require a far-away object to perform a `refresh()` of its own state.

Example 3: Going back to Example 1, some objects spread throughout the app provide various bits of content to `send_daily_status_messages()`.

To address this, our team has created an Events class that centralizes all of these calls. However we're finding the Events class itself to be a bit too "distant", in the sense that sometimes we make changes in the distributed objects, forget to make changes to the calls within the Events class, and then see bugs.

I'm wondering if there are any better patterns out there?

One thought: For objects to "register" themselves to some sort of dynamic Events class upon initialization. That would keep the invocation code near each object. Objects could maybe even also create different Events?

Lastly, this is for a Perl-based web application that using Moose. So any Perl-specific Moose-friendly recommendations, including CPAN recommendations, would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common pattern that sounds like what you're talking about is event dispatch. You can find many different takes on this pattern on CPAN, such as: [Event::Distributor](https://metacpan.org/pod/Event::Distributor), [Beam::Emitter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Beam::Emitter), [Mixin::Event::Dispatch](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mixin::Event::Dispatch), [Mojo::EventEmitter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::EventEmitter) (which I've extracted to a [role](https://metacpan.org/pod/Role::EventEmitter)). You have some object which is either an event dispatcher or has an event dispatching role applied to it, and everything can subscribe to events, and when something emits an event all of the subscribers get their callback called.

Comment: Thanks for the answer & CPAN suggestions!  I'm having a chicken & egg moment.  How does an object subscribe itself (or more specifically, a callback method of itself) if it hasn't yet been instantiated?  Using Moose here.  Code sample would be super useful!

Comment: I'm not really following the use case - it sounds like a specific setup that maybe you could expand on in your question?

Comment: I edited question a bit, but think it's probably a good idea to keep it open to other generalized approaches. As to the specifics for using the modules you suggested:  We're using Moose.  So if we have Moose class say `Class1` with `some_method()` that we would like to dispatch events to, where would be a good place to add code where, upon firing of the event, creates an instance of Class1 and then runs `some_method()`?  Also where do I initialize -- ie create event?  (presumably some initialization code that runs once to point events to some_method())

Comment: Any code you want to run upon the event firing should just go in the callback. They're closures, you can close over variables in outer scopes as needed (this is a common way to do "initialize once", alternatively there's [state](https://perldoc.pl/functions/state)), or just run whatever code you need. It's hard to say what the optimal structure would be without a complete understanding of the code.

Comment: You have looked at the classic Observer Pattern as in GoF? This or some variation would seem to fit what you describe. "Observers" register with a "Subject". Subject "notifies" Observers on state change/event etc by invoking Observer methods.